# How to force a full resync on a SharedIndexInformer in a custom controller

Tags: go, kubernetes, controller, client-go

I'm writing a custom controller for Kubernetes in Go with the help of [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/).
It is based on the [sample-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller) and working great so far.

The `SharedIndexInformer` has the option to periodically resync all objects. ([Parameter `resyncPeriod`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/203d909765c952c466d36786ec7adf13d40f2281/tools/cache/shared_informer.go#L170) is set to 30 seconds in the [sample-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller/blob/d90ced32cf661b9821ecb20b08502ad62377a035/main.go#L63).)

*Is there a way to force a resync immediately?*

The code which seems to handle the periodic resync seems to call [`store.Resync()`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/203d909765c952c466d36786ec7adf13d40f2281/tools/cache/reflector.go#L332).
I've tried calling `fooInformer.Informer().GetStore().Resync()`. The call succeeds, but the resync is not happening. What did I miss?

---

I'm using `client-go` `v0.17.2` and the server is EKS `v1.14.9-eks-c0eccc`.

Comment: What are the server/client versions?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that. I've added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

The `cache.Store` that does the periodic resync is instantiated in `newInformer` in `k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/controller.go` as a `cache.DeltaFIFO` queue:

```
    // This will hold incoming changes. Note how we pass clientState in as a
    // KeyLister, that way resync operations will result in the correct set
    // of update/delete deltas.
    fifo := NewDeltaFIFOWithOptions(DeltaFIFOOptions{
        KnownObjects:          clientState,
        EmitDeltaTypeReplaced: true,
    })
```

This is returned by `cache.New()` as an unexported field `cache.controller{}.config.Queue`, which there is no exported function for accessing- so no way to manually call `Resync()`.

Answer (score 1):

Upon calling `fooInformer.Informer().GetStore().Resync()` you are using `Resync` function/method of the Store type defined in: client-go/tools/cache/store.go

And there we can see the following:

In the Store type definition:

```
// Resync is meaningless in the terms appearing here but has
// meaning in some implementations that have non-trivial
// additional behavior (e.g., DeltaFIFO).
Resync() error
```

And in the Resync definition further below:

```
// Resync is meaningless for one of these
func (c *cache) Resync() error {
return nil
}
```

Unless you actually have some other class to do the Resync, this is supposed to really do nothing.

That is why

> The call succeeds, but the resync is not happening.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by listing every object from the informer store, then calling ResourceEventHandlerFuncs's `AddFunc` (usually `xxxController.OnAddXxx`).

```golang
for _, v := range xxxController.xxxInformer.GetStore().List() {
    xxxController.OnAddXxx(v)
}
```

---

Or, if you'd like to hack, you can use reflect

```golang
field := reflect.ValueOf(xxxController.xxxInformer).Elem().FieldByName("controller").Elem().Elem().FieldByName("reflector").Elem().FieldByName("store")
reflect.NewAt(field.Type(), unsafe.Pointer(field.UnsafeAddr())).Elem().Interface().(*cache.DeltaFIFO).Resync()
```